# Limit GCI after count reaches a certain number in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I currently use a script that monitors the number of files in some key folders for an operations team to keep an eye on and make decisions based on the numbers.  The script works well, as below:

```
$folders = @("c:\temp", "C:\temp\tosh")
$results = @()
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $folderFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "abc*.xml" }
    $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Folder = $folder
        Count = $folderFiles.count
    }
    $results += $obj
}
$results | format-table
```

I do however have an issue when the number of `xml` files in one of the folders is large (20k+ or so) and the GCI will take 60s+ to return the results.

I'm wondering, is there a way where I can stop the GCI if the `$folderFiles` object gets to a set amount, such as a count of 5000?  This would enable me to just show 5000+ as the file count in the `$results` table.

I've thought about using `Select-Object` but presume that this will perform the entire GCI then only limit after it finishes?

```
$folderFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $folder -File | Select-Object -First 5000
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: *I've thought about using Select-Object but presume that this will perform the entire GCI then only limit after it finishes?* Do not presume. Test. Don't ask questions that you can easily answer yourself by simply trying it out.

Comment: I think [why is get childitem so slow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow/) is still relevant with newer versions of PS.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  Agreed, I will test when the situation arises again, but at present, there are only low numbers of files in folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this with a smaller sample to see what the result would be like. `Measure-Command` is a helpful tool to see how portions of code perform:

Here's a test I did against a folder of about 500 files:

```
Measure-Command { Get-ChildItem -File }

Measure-Command { Get-ChildItem -File | Select-Object -First 250 }
```

Result:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 26
Ticks             : 263370
TotalDays         : 3.04826388888889E-07
TotalHours        : 7.31583333333333E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.00043895
TotalSeconds      : 0.026337
TotalMilliseconds : 26.337

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 13
Ticks             : 132462
TotalDays         : 1.533125E-07
TotalHours        : 3.6795E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.00022077
TotalSeconds      : 0.0132462
TotalMilliseconds : 13.2462
```

You can see that using the `Select` did improve the performance of the code.